# Extremely slow parsing text with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, swift3, substring

I'm trying to parse a 46k characters text document and it takes forever to do so. Here's what I do :

```
    for i in 0..<html.length() - SEARCH_START.length() {
        if html.substring(i, end: i+SEARCH_START.length()) == SEARCH_START {
                start = i + SEARCH_START.length();
                break;
        }
        if i % 1000 == 0 {
            NSLog("i = \(i)")
        }
    }

extension String {

    public func length () -> Int {
        return self.characters.count
    }
    public func substring(_ start : Int, end : Int) -> String {
        if self.characters.count <= 0 {
            return ""
        }
        let realEnd = end>0 ? end : 0
        return self.substring(with: self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: start)..<self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: realEnd))
    }
}
```

Sorry, had to extend String class to do less rewriting from Android.
So, Log is being triggered each 6.5 seconds for a next thousand means **almost 5 minutes** to get to the end. The wole process should take milliseconds. What's the deal? Any way to speed it up?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  What's the actual parsing?

Comment: i think there are better methods to find a substring. or with Scanner you can analyze a string.

Comment: consider a parsing library like https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `Int` indexing extension is the problem. To get a substring at position `n`, it needs to go through all the characters `0..n`. Therefore your algorithm has `O(n^2)` (quadratic) complexity instead of the expected `O(n)` (linear) complexity.

Don't use that extension.

To search for a substring, there is a native method

```
if let range = html.range(of: SEARCH_START) {
    let integerIndex = html.distance(from: html.startIndex, to: range.upperBound)
    print(integerIndex)
}
```

If you really want to work with integers, you should convert your string to an array of characters first:

```
let chars = Array(html.characters)
```

and work with subarrays instead of substrings.

Edit:

To better understand what happens in your extension:

```
self.substring(with: self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: start)..<self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: realEnd))
```

In Java, where `String` is an array and supports random indexing this would be a constant (fast) operation. However, in Swift this is composed from 3 steps:

1. `self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: start)` iterates from the first character until it finds the character at index `start`.
2. `self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: realEnd))` iterates from the first character until it finds the character at index `realEnd`.
3. Gets the substring (fast)

In short, for every substring at start position `n`, the algorithm has to iterate over `2n` characters. To get a single substring at index `20000`, you need `40000` operations!

Comment: thanks, but it's a quite uncomfortable thing. Why did they make a linked list out of String :/

Comment: @user2976267 it's not a linked list. The problem is that the characters don't have the same byte size. The implementation in other languages is actually the one that is problematic nowadays. As I said in my answer, you can always get the array of characters when needed but doing that automatically would hit the performance big time. Just use the correct native functions.